# Copy a div to a text file

Tags: jquery, file, html, clone

needing some help here with jquery. I have a div i want to copy to a text file. This div has a class, and inside this div, there is some other divs and some other elements, but no one with the same .class as the main div. I'm not sure if i am able to use .clone() So what i need is something like this:

```
$('.myClass').misteriousCopyFunction('toTextFile');
//as i said, i'm not sure about this.
```

and my html looks like this

```
...
<div class="myClass">
  *lots of stuff*
  *lots of stuff*
  *lots of stuff*
</div>
...
```

it's just a little piece of the Html code to output to a new file in the current folder.
Sorry if i said something stupid =P

Comment: You cannot do this with only jQuery. You will need to send the data by ajax to some server side solution that will produce the file.

Comment: As for selecting everything in a div, $('.myClass').html() will give you what you need regardless of what's inside .myClass.

Comment: JavaScript in the browser has no access to your filesystem for security reasons. You need to do this in the client side. If you want to use JS then NodeJS is what you need, or else PHP, Ruby, Python with some AJAX magic.

Comment: If you want to get a copy of the div contents with html tags included, use the jQuery method `html()`. In case you just want the text inside that div, `text()` will suit you.

Comment: It was supposed to be in the client side, I forgot to mention. Thanks for the answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using some [new HTML features](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download) currently only available in Chrome I believe.  Basically you save the contents of the DIV using the FileSystem APi and then create a link that has a `download` attribute pointing to the file.

Comment: That helps, but i needed it to be automatic, doing it on 550 pages would take a while. And doing it every day would suck. But, i'll take a look at this. Thanks